# Pawn, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, connection, pawn

I am trying to connect to my MySQL host in Hostinger from Pawn language ...
I do not know why I am getting these errors:

```
[17:25:26] [ERROR] CMySQLConnection::Connect - (error #2005) Unknown MySQL
server host 'mysql.hostinger.co.il' (0)
[17:25:26] [WARNING] CMySQLConnection::Disconnect - no connection available
[17:25:26] [ERROR] CMySQLConnection::Connect - (error #2005) Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql.hostinger.co.il' (0)
[17:25:26] [WARNING] CMySQLConnection::Disconnect - no connection available
[17:25:26] [ERROR] CMySQLConnection::Connect - (error #2005) Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql.hostinger.co.il' (0)
[17:25:26] [WARNING] CMySQLConnection::Disconnect - no connection available
```

I will be very happy to get help.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious, 'mysql.hostinger.co.il' is not valid mysql host. If you're trying to make remote connection, remote connection may be disallowed by Hostinger. If otherwise, just type 'localhost' instead of 'mysql.hostinger.co.il'